# getServerSideProps in dynamic paths

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a dynamic route named [...uri].
And For you inform; I have a 2 path to enter this page. /test1 & /test2

Whenever I open /test1 path its works. But whenever I route to test2 path from test1 page, Its not re-render getServerSideProps so its not works.
How can i solve this issue ? Its my simple getServerSideProps code example.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  console.log('GET INITIAL PROPS !!!',ctx)
  return {
    props: { namespaces: ctx.resolvedUrl??"null" }, //Its always showing /test1 in props.
  }
}
```

Comment: How you are going from test1 to test2? Your question is not complete enough. Please make it a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the uri parts from the params prop that is passed to the component (assuming the correct folder layout.

```
app
  | [...uri]
           | page.tsx
```

The contents of `page.tsx` could be:

```
export default function MyComponent({
  params,
}: {
  params: {
    uri: string[];
  };
}) {
  return <h1>you are on page {params.uri[0]}</h1>
}
```

Here's a video tutorial that may help if this still isn't clear: https://youtu.be/Ssw6-69KLRo?si=rq6IoKS7UKRpGv7D

Comment: thanks for response but but thing is, I don't using app router. I using pages router still. So its not works. And i need some api request or etc in getServerSideProps too.

Comment: Update the OP to say such and you will get relevant help.